# Trying to use colormap to replace color in png, with a gradient to transparent

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have some code that opens a transparent png with a black object on it, it successfully replaces the black section using a colormap.  The issue is for a png that has an object that fades from black to transparent, the color map is only replacing the first few pixels of true black and leaving the gradient to transparent untouched.  I am hoping for some help!  I am not clear on how the semi transparent pixels are colored, or how i would replace them.  Existing code below:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ChangeImageColor(Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("test.png")), Color.Black, Color.Blue)
End Sub

Public Sub ChangeImageColor(ByVal image As System.Drawing.Image, ByVal oldColor As System.Drawing.Color, ByVal newColor As System.Drawing.Color)
    Try
        Dim newImage As System.Drawing.Image = DirectCast(image.Clone, System.Drawing.Image)
        Dim g1 As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
        Dim colorMap(0) As System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMap

        colorMap(0) = New System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMap
        colorMap(0).OldColor = oldColor
        colorMap(0).NewColor = newColor

        Dim imageAttr As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes = New System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes
        imageAttr.SetThreshold(0.7, ColorAdjustType.Default)

        imageAttr.SetRemapTable(colorMap)

        g1.DrawImage(newImage, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height), 0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height, Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttr)

        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream

        Response.ContentType = "image/png"
        newImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png)
        ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)

        newImage.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```